# HK2 bind multiple copies of an implementation to a contract, each with different constructor arguments?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inject, hk2

Using HK2 in Java, is there a way to bind multiple instances of the same implementation class to the same contract with different qualifiers and different constructor arguments.

Here is a contrived example:

```
@Service
@Singleton
public class Circle extends Shape
{
  @Inject
  public Circle(final Pen pen)
  {
    // This pen could be RED or BLUE etc.
    this.pen = pen;
  }
}

bind(Circle.class)
  .to(Shape.class)
  .named("red circle")
  // I would like something like this.
  // This would inject a "Pen" instance qualified by "red" into the Circle.
  .withConstructorArg(0, Pen.class, "red");

bind(Circle.class)
  .to(Shape.class)
  .named("blue circle")
  // This would inject a "Pen" instance qualified by "blue" into the Circle.
  .withConstructorArg(0, Pen.class, "blue");

// Then later in the code I can inject either one.
@Inject
public void MyCtor(@Named("red circle") Shape red, @Named("blue circle") Shape blue)
...
```

So far, the only way I have seen to accomplish this is to make a base class and then create a separate leaf classes that extends the base class (one for EACH variant).

Is there a better way to do this?